# XSLT using templates, am i on the right way?

Tags: xml, parsing, xslt

I'm new to XSLT, but recently I had to write my own xslt to process the XML, I wrote something, but I would like to ask the professionals, if I did it good, or is there is something more i could do to improve.

I know XSLT uses the templates and stuff, but in my XSLT i think there is too much of repeatable stuff in the tests ... can it be reduced?

Here is my XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="Today" />
  <xsl:param name="ViewType" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>Priority</th>
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Due date</th>
        </tr>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="All_Results/Result">
        <xsl:sort select="duedate" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
     </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Result">
    <xsl:variable name="varOverdue" select="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(duedate))) &lt; ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today)))" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="varOverduePlus14" select="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(duedate))) &lt; ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today)))+12096000000000" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1"/>
    <xsl:variable name="varOverdueToday" select="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(duedate))) = ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today)))" ddwrt:cf_explicit="1"/>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$ViewType='active'">

            <xsl:if test="($varOverdue=0) and (taskstatus ='In Progress')">          
                <tr>                
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="priority"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                          <xsl:value-of  select="url"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="title">
                          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        </a>                          
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:value-of select="duedate"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:if>

        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$ViewType='overdue'">
            <xsl:if test="($varOverdue=1) and (taskstatus !='Completed')">          
                <tr>                
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="priority"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                          <xsl:value-of  select="url"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="title">
                          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        </a>                          
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:attribute name="style">
                           color:red;
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:value-of select="duedate"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$ViewType='upcoming'">      
            <xsl:if test="(taskstatus !='Completed') and ($varOverduePlus14=1)">          
                <tr>                
                    <td><xsl:value-of select="priority"/></td>
                    <td>
                        <a>
                        <xsl:attribute name="href">
                          <xsl:value-of  select="url"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        <xsl:attribute name="title">
                          <xsl:value-of select="title"/>
                        </xsl:attribute>
                        </a>                          
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <xsl:if test="$varOverdue=1">
                            <xsl:attribute name="style">
                               color:red;
                            </xsl:attribute>
                        </xsl:if>
                        <xsl:value-of select="duedate"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </xsl:if>           
        </xsl:when>
    </xsl:choose>

  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The XML looks like this:

```
<All_Results>
    <Result>
      <id>1</id>
      <workid>2258</workid>
      ...
    </Result>
    <Result>
      <id>2</id>
      <workid>4537</workid>
      ....
    </Result>
    ...
</All_Results>
```

So is there a way to improve my XSLT to parse the current XML?

Comment: Posting your expected output would help people analyze your XSLT & suggest improvements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to consolidate this considerably, like this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:ddwrt="http://schemas.microsoft.com/WebParts/v2/DataView/runtime">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:param name="Today" />
  <xsl:param name="ViewType" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>Priority</th>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th>Due date</th>
      </tr>
      <xsl:variable name="results" select="All_Results/Result" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="$results[1]">
        <xsl:sort select="duedate" />
        <xsl:with-param name="remaining" select="$results[position() > 1]" />
      </xsl:apply-templates>
    </table>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Result">
    <xsl:param name="num" select="1" />
    <xsl:param name="remaining" select="/.." />

    <xsl:variable name="dueDateTick"
                select="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string(duedate)))" />
    <xsl:variable name="todayTick"
                select="ddwrt:DateTimeTick(ddwrt:GenDisplayName(string($Today)))" />

    <xsl:variable name="varOverdue" select="$dueDateTick &lt; $todayTick"
                  ddwrt:cf_explicit="1" />
    <xsl:variable name="varOverduePlus14"
                  select="$dueDateTick &lt; $todayTick +12096000000000"
                  ddwrt:cf_explicit="1" />
    <xsl:variable name="varOverdueToday" select="$dueDateTick = $todayTick"
                  ddwrt:cf_explicit="1"/>

    <xsl:variable name="shouldInclude"
                  select="($ViewType = 'active' and not($varOverdue) 
                           and taskstatus = 'In Progress') or
                          ($ViewType = 'overdue' and $varOverdue and 
                           taskstatus != 'Completed') or
                          ($ViewType = 'upcoming' and taskstatus != 'Completed' and 
                           $varOverduePlus14)" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[$shouldInclude]"
                         mode="content">
      <xsl:with-param name="varOverdue" select="$varOverdue" />
      <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>

    <xsl:apply-templates select="$remaining[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="num" select="$num + $shouldInclude" />
      <xsl:with-param name="remaining" select="$remaining[position() > 1]" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Result" mode="content">
    <xsl:param name="varOverdue" />
    <xsl:param name="num" />

    <tr>
      <td>
        <xsl:value-of select="priority"/>
      </td>
      <td>
        <a href="{url}" title="{title}">
          You'll need some text here
        </a>
      </td>
      <td>
        <xsl:if test="$num mod 2 = 0">
          <xsl:attribute name="class">ms-alternating ms-itmhover</xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:if>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="current()[$varOverdue]"
                             mode="dueDateStyle" />
        <xsl:value-of select="duedate"/>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*" mode="dueDateStyle">
    <xsl:attribute name="style">
      <xsl:text>color: red;</xsl:text>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I'm unable to test this because I don't have access to the extension functions you're using, but please give this a try and let me know how it goes.

Comment: I dont know will it work? Just the thing is i probably forgot to say, due to paramter i send, is this active / overdue or upcoming, the correct tasks should show, but what i see here everything will be rendered, not regarding the parameter viewtype. Or maybe i couldn't understand very well, ill recheck

Comment: Oh nice it did work it seems, but how could i add alternating to this?

Comment: What do you mean by "alternating"?

Comment: By alternating i mean, like you have tables and rows and one row is has alternating class added to it another not, i did like this: <tr class="ms-itmhover">
  <xsl:if test="position() mod 2 = 0">
   <xsl:attribute name="class">
    ms-alternating ms-itmhover
   </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:if> (but it doesnt work)

Comment: Ok, since items are conditionally included based on a rather complex condition, this is a bit tricky, but the recursive solution above should work.